# GNURadio Viterbi with custom spec

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, viterbi, forwarderrorcorrection

I have a convolutional code with r=1/2, k=7, G1 = 1111001 and G2=1011011 (see CCSDS 131.0-B-4 basic convolutional coding, https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/131x0b4.pdf, section 3.3.1) but I'm NOT using the symbol inversion.

As far as I can tell, the GNU radio "Decode CCSDS 27" Module from gr-satellites "only" supports the same algorithm but WITH inversion.

I'm not an expert on convolution coding so maybe there is a simple way to use the "Decode CCSDS 27" and make the system support the "without symbol inversion".

I would like some suggestions of GNU radio modules that could help support the requested algorithm.

Thanks in advance